# How to determine if a function has been called in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, function-call

I have a Big Script where i want to ignore a function call if it has been called already.

Am having a flag which is set to determine this now. But how do i do this without needing to have a flag or count for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the function re-write itself, essentially becoming a noop after the first invocation:

```
function TestFunction
 {
   'Do Stuff'
   function Script:TestFunction { Return }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome!! That was what i was looking for. Simple stuff, thanks!!

Comment: This seems to be in effect for the entire powershell session? Is there a way i can check this for each script run, even in the same powershell session ?

Comment: Are you testing in the ISE, or an actual Powershell console session?  The Script:TestFunction should isolate it to just the scope of the current script, but scoping works a little differently in the ISE.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help you:

```
function A
{
    Write-Host "calling function A"
}

function B
{
    Write-Host "calling function B"
}

function C
{
    Write-Host "calling function C"
}

function All
{
    A

    if (!$script:BHasBeenCalled)
        { B }

    C
}

Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command B -Action { $script:BHasBeenCalled = $true } | Out-Null

$script:bHasBeenCalled = $false

#First call: B should be invoked
All

#Second call: B shouldn't be invoked
All
```

Answer (score -1):

If the function has already been called, it's loaded and appears in the function Ps drive.

```
function test1 {
    # define a function
    function test2 {return}
    # call it
    test2
    # check it was called
    dir function:\test2
}
test1
```